# Search Index not coming back after Search Index Reset

Tags: 2013, search, index-reset

I reset the search index about 24 hours ago but it has yet to come back. Is there anything else I can do to help it come back?

A full crawl has been performed many times after the reset. The site has 3 subsites with about 50 lists each.

Comment: After resetting the index did you initiate a full crawl? Is the crawl still running? How much content is in your farm?

Comment: yes, i did a full crawl many times after the reset.  The site has 3 subsites with about 50 lists each.

Answer (score 0):

I had Windows Auth turned off...

"URL being crawled must be a Windows Authenticated zone." - [from here](https://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/sharepoint-2013-configuring-search-to-crawl-web-applications-using-claims-and-adfs-2-0/)

"In order for the SharePoint Search to crawl content we need to configure “Windows Authentication” on at least one zone in the Web Application." - [from here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2013/02/20/beware-crawling-the-non-default-zone-for-a-sharepoint-2013-web-application/)